# XSL XPath help when following siblings contain 2 child elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I am having problems coming up with an XPath statement that will help me create a table of contents from Excel XML.

Here is my basic Excel XML structure:

```
<Table>
<Row>
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">Title 1</Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2">
        <Data ss:Type="String">Subtitle1</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">Filename1</Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2">
        <Data ss:Type="String">Subtitle2</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">Filename2</Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2">
        <Data ss:Type="String">Subtitle3</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">Filename3</Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">Title 2</Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2">
        <Data ss:Type="String">Subtitle1</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">Filename1</Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2">
        <Data ss:Type="String">Subtitle2</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">Filename2</Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2">
        <Data ss:Type="String">Subtitle3</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">Filename3</Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
<Row>
    <Cell ss:Index="2">
        <Data ss:Type="String">Subtitle4</Data>
    </Cell>
    <Cell>
        <Data ss:Type="String">Filename4</Data>
    </Cell>
</Row>
```

As shown above, I have two titles that each have a single Cell element, and I need to be able to grab the following siblings that contain two Cell elements. I need the output to look like:

```
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Title 1</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-src="Filename1">Subtitle1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-src="Filename2">Subtitle2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-src="Filename3">Subtitle3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="sub">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);">Title 2</a>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-src="Filename1">Subtitle1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-src="Filename2">Subtitle2</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-src="Filename3">Subtitle3</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-src="Filename4">Subtitle4</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I would provide some code, but I am afraid I haven't gotten too far. I am a noob when it comes to XSLT.

Comment: Can you use XSLT 2.0 for this?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **XSLT 1.0** solution

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="Table">
        <ul class="nav">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[count(Cell)=1]"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row[count(Cell)=1]">
        <li class="sub">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);"><xsl:value-of select="Cell/Data"/></a>
            <ul>
                <xsl:variable name="heading" select="."/>
                <xsl:apply-templates 
                      select="following-sibling::Row[Cell[2]]
                                [generate-id(preceding-sibling::Row[count(Cell)=1][1]) = 
                                                 generate-id($heading)]"/>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row[Cell[2]]">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-src="{ Cell[2]/Data }">
              <xsl:value-of select="Cell[1]/Data"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Very nice, Mads! I was unaware of the ability to match in the format of 'Row[count(Cell)=1'. Super appreciate the guidance.

Comment: I do want to clarify that the third template data-src and value of the anchor tag are reversed (for those looking for a similar solution).

Comment: Whoops! I have adjusted the XPath to select the appropriate values for `@data-src` and the anchor text.

Answer (score 2):

And this is another way (copied **Mads Hansen**'s answer) using `xsl:key`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>

    <xsl:key name="element" match="Row[Cell[2]]" use="generate-id(preceding::Row[count(Cell) = 1][1])"/>

    <xsl:template match="Table">
        <ul class="nav">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Row[count(Cell)=1]"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row[count(Cell)=1]">
        <li class="sub">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);">
                <xsl:value-of select="Cell/Data"/>
            </a>
            <ul>
                <xsl:apply-templates  select="key('element', generate-id())"/>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Row[Cell[2]]">
        <li>
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-src="{ Cell[2]/Data }">
                <xsl:value-of select="Cell[1]/Data"/>
            </a>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```